# Declarative helper within razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I have the following code in mvc:

```cs
<a class="cta-icon-link" >
    @Html.RenderMediaData(Model.Icon, new { TypeCssClasses = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "imageFile", "cta-icon" }, { "VectorImageFile", "cta-icon" } } })
</a>
<a class="@cssClass" >@Model.LinkText</a>
```

So basically the sequence is as follows:

```cs
if condition()
{
    <a>
    <image>
    </a>
}
<a/>
```

Now, what is required is I have another condition which will decide the placement of the above code:

```cs
if (placement==left)
{
    if condition()
    {
        <a>
        <image>
        </a>
    }
    <a/>
}
else
{
    <a/>
    if condition()
    {
        <a>
        <image>
        </a>
    }
}
```

Is there a way to use declarative helper method within cshtml to achieve this without repeating the code?

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work like this
by adding `@`

```
@if (placement == left)
{
    if condition()
    {
        <a>
            <image>
        </a>
    }
    <a />
}
else
{
    <a />
    if condition()
    {
        <a>
            <image>
        </a>
    }
}
```

Comment: This is one of the way to start with but if you see there is a lot of repetitive code here.so rather than repeating the code ,I would like to use declarative helper functions.

Comment: It might be repetitive in the code, but you will get the required result.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
@if (placement == left&&condition())
{
    <a>
        <image>
    </a>
    <a />
}
else if (placement != left&&condition())
{
    <a />
    <a>
        <image>
    </a>
}
else
{
    </a>
}
```

Or you can try to use the conditional operator `?:` to replace if,else,here is an [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator):

```
@(placement == left?(condition()?Html.Raw("<a><image></a><a />"):Html.Raw("<a />")): (condition()? Html.Raw("<a /><a><image></a>") : Html.Raw("<a />")))
```